# Call to a member function has() on null (render method) Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have 2 bundles:

1) UserBundle with class RememberController

```
namespace UserBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use MailEventBundle\Controller\MailEventController;

class RememberController extends Controller
{
    public function rememberAction(Request $request)
        {
        if($request->get('email') != null){

            $params = 
            [
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'subject' => 'Remind password', 
                'template' => 'template/remember.html',
                'values' => array(
                    'password' => md5($request->get('email') . date("l dS of F Y h:i:s A"))
                    )
            ];

            $MailEventController = new MailEventController();

            $MailEventController->mailGenerator($params);

            return new Response(
                'Almost ok',
                Response::HTTP_OK
            );
        }
    }


}
```

If i call render method in this class, all works good! But if i call render method in MailEventController i have error Call to a member function has() on null, also i call $this->container and return null from MailEventController

2) MailEventController

```
namespace MailEventBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MailEventController extends Controller
{
    private function sendAction($message)
    {
        try {
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
            return true;
        } catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }

    public function mailGenerator($params)
    {
       $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject($params['subject'])
            ->setFrom('email@email.com')
            ->setTo($params['email'])
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView( // error here
                    $params['template'],
                    $params['values']
                ),
                'text/html'
            );


       return $this->sendAction($message);

    }

}
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: `$MailEventController = new MailEventController();` this is not how you work with controllers.  What is your MalEventController supposed to do? It extends the Base Symfony Controller, but it doesn't look like it's an actual controller in the sense of a MVC framework? It looks like it's supposed to be a service.

Comment: Premising that a controller must return a Response, you should use DI Services to handle reusable logic and not controller methods. You should read more deeper the docs.

Comment: Yes it is a service but I wrote it in the form of bundle, and the service can have a render method? Is there an example of correct implementation?

Comment: No it is not an example of a correct implementation.  Really mixing up to notion of controllers and other services.  Take a look at the services section in the manual.  Having said that, I suppose you could cheat with $MailEventController->setContainer($this->container);  But don't do that.